# Wisper como alternativa ao Observer Design Pattern no RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou tentando implementar o [Wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper/wiki/ActiveRecord-Callbacks) como alternativa ao Observer Design Pattern que foi descontinuado do Ruby.

O erro é: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

O método que criei é basicamente para executar um puts "Um restaurante recebeu uma qualificação".

Estou estudando a apostila RR77 da Caelum.

https://gist.github.com/emanoelopes/7bf3d5fcbf1a6f1a44d199dcceefa0f9

Comment: Deu certo! Meu colega de trabalho me explicou e conseguimos fazer. https://github.com/emanoelopes/cp2-rails/tree/master/cp2-caelum-apostila/vota_prato

Answer (score 1):

Conseguimos. O código está disponível em: https://github.com/emanoelopes/cp2-rails/tree/master/cp2-caelum-apostila/vota_prato